# Flutter not building aab file

Tags: flutter, apk

Am trying to build a `release bundle` for my app. It doesn't work at all as it just exits. What could be wrong?

[image]

Comment: What happen if you run: flutter build appbundle

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Follow the instruction here: https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/android#building-the-app-for-release

The command should be: `flutter build appbundle`

(Of course, you need to setup keystore info in your build.gradle first)